# Getting a handle for one of the axes in a 2D plot in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, handle, axes

I am learning the basics of Octave.
I want to get a handle `hax` to only one of the axes of a 2D plot in Octave, e.g., the x axis.
Then I would like to use it to set, e.g., the limits for that axis, possibly within a function that takes `hax` as an argument.

So I would have (with whatever field names were correct)

```
function retval = set_axis(hax, limits, label)
   set(hax, 'limits', limits)
   set(hax, 'label', label)
   ...
   retval = ...
endfunction
```

and this would work without needing to know which specific axis I am working with.

**Can this be done? How?**

Comment: 'axes' means something different in octave. in any case you can do this with the `xlim` function (or alternatively, the `xlim` property of an `axes` graphics object).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - Please see posted answer.

Comment: note that `axis` is also a specific function in octave (like 'axes'). If you don't want to risk overshadowing core functions in general, you could use variables that start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer for how to get a handle for one of the axes only,
but it helps performing the example actions described in the OP.

At least for functions `xlim` and `xlabel` (and its `y` and `z` counterparts), one could use

```
function y = set_axis_limits_label(hax, axis, axislabel, limits)

    set( hax, [ axis 'label' ], axislabel );
    set( hax, [ axis 'lim' ], limits );
```

where `axis` is expected to receive `'x'`, `'y'` or `'z'`.

The "burden" of knowing which axis to deal with is not on the handle but on the property name to be set.
It's not what I would find the cleanest, but it works.